# why android front facing camera previewcallback return big data

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

First,my mobile is Samsung S3. I want to get the preview data from the front facing camera,but the returned data is so big,the data length is 1036800(>1M),the camera preview size is 320*240 and preview format is NV21. But the data length from the back facing camera is 115200(about 112KB) with the same preview size and preview format.Anybody can help me? Why?

Front facing camera parameters:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
//mCamera.startFaceDetection();
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
```

Comment: Could you please post a bit more of your code? Do you set back the parameters to your camera instance?

Comment: Did you forget to copy the line `mCamera.setParameters(parameters);` or you forgot to put it in your code?

Comment: At any rate, in your `onPreviewFrame()` callback you can access the camera (it's the second parameter), call `camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize()`, and check what really happens.

Comment: Thank Alex Cohn. You are right 0.0